# How to count how many rows in DataFrame where "start" and "end" columns contain a certain date?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like

```
        Category   Start       End
0          a     2014-12-01 2015-06-01
1          a     2015-10-02 2015-10-16
2          b     2015-10-01 2016-04-01
3          b     2015-10-01 2015-12-01
4          c     2015-06-01 2015-08-01
```

For each date in a range of dates d, id like to find all rows where start <= date<= end, then I'd like to count how many distinct category's there is.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

d = pd.date_range(start='2015-01-01', end='2015-12-31', freq='D')
s = {'Start':[datetime.date(2014,12,1), datetime.date(2015,10,2), datetime.date(2015,10,1), datetime.date(2015,10,1), datetime.date(2015,6,1)]}
e = {'End':[datetime.date(2015,6,1), datetime.date(2015,10,16), datetime.date(2016,4,1), datetime.date(2015,12,1), datetime.date(2015,8,1)]}
c = {'Category': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']}
c.update(s)
c.update(e)
df = pd.DataFrame(c)
df_count = pd.DataFrame(index=d, col['count']

for date in d:
   count_occourances = len(set(df.loc[(df['Start'] <= date) & (df['End'] >= date), 'Category']))
   # Some saving to keep track on count for this particular date e.g.
   df_count.loc[date, 'count'] = count_occourances
```

Then the expected output would
df_count :

```
        Category   Count      
2015-01-01          1    
2015-01-02          1    
2015-01-03          1    
2015-01-04          1     
2015-01-05          1     
    .
    .
    .
2015-05-31          1
2015-06-01          2
2015-06-02          1
2015-06-03          1
    .
    .
    .
2015-07-31          1
2015-08-01          1
2015-08-02          0
    .
    .
    .
2015-09-30          0
2015-10-01          2
2015-10-02          3
2015-10-03          3
    .
    .
    .
2015-10-15          3
2015-10-16          3
2015-10-17          2
    .
    .
    .
2015-12-01          2
2015-12-02          1
    .
    .
    .
2015-12-31          1
```

Comment: `how many distinct categories`, so `df.loc[(df["Start"]<=date)&(df["End"]>=date), "Category"].nunique()`?

Comment: when you say a given date `d`, it is a single date value correct? ex: `08-20-2021` and not as per your example for `d` which states `d = pd.date_range(start='2015-01-01', end='2015-12-31', freq='D')` ?

Comment: @JoeFerndz great observation. For each date in d, I'd like to find all rows where start <= date <= end and count how many distinct categorys there is

Comment: @Olba12, kindly add the expected output. A visual would be helpful and streamline possible solutions

Comment: I've mad an edit. @sammywemmy

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you can achieve this via intervals:

Convert the dates to datetime dtype:

```
df = df.assign(Start = df.Start.transform(pd.to_datetime), 
               End = df.End.transform(pd.to_datetime))
```

Create intervalindex:

```
intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df.Start, df.End, closed='both')
```

Create a dictionary, pairing the  unique counts with the individual dates:

```
  counter = {}
  category = df.Category.array
  for dates in d:
      booleans = intervals.contains(dates)
      count = category[booleans].unique().size
      counter[dates] = count
```

You can then create a Series:

```
series = pd.Series(counter)
series.index.name = 'Category'
series.name = 'counter'

series.head()

Category
2015-01-01    1
2015-01-02    1
2015-01-03    1
2015-01-04    1
2015-01-05    1
Name: counter, dtype: int64
```

Since these are intervals, you should get significant speed up, assuming I got the question right

Comment: I think your solution fits better OP's requirement than mine and is benchmarked to be very good among the answers.  Upvoted +1

Answer (score 1):

You can add a helper column to count the number of overlapping days between date range `d` and the date range between `Start` and `End` on each row.  Then, filter on rows these overlapping days > 0.  Finally, count the number of distinct `Category` on the filtered rows:

1. Convert dates to datetime format, if not already in datetime format:

```
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'])
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'])
```

2. On each row, create the date range between `Start` and `End` dates by `pd.date_range()`.  Then, get the overlapping date range with date range `d` by numpy function [`np.intersect1d()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) (to get the intersection between the 2 date ranges).  Get the number of overlapping days by getting the length of the intersection.

```
df['overlap_days'] = df.apply(lambda x: len(np.intersect1d(pd.date_range(start=x['Start'], end=x['End'], freq='D'), d)), axis=1)
```

Result:

```
print(df)

  Category      Start        End  overlap_days
0        a 2014-12-01 2015-06-01           152
1        a 2015-10-02 2015-10-16            15
2        b 2015-10-01 2016-04-01            92
3        b 2015-10-01 2015-12-01            62
4        c 2015-06-01 2015-08-01            62
```

3. Filter on rows with overlapping days > 0 by `.loc` and count the number of distinct `Category` on the filtered rows by [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html), as follows:

```
df.loc[df['overlap_days'] > 0, 'Category'].nunique()
```

**Output:**

```
3
```

**Performance Consideration**

This solution uses fast vectorized Numpy operation under the hood.  Although it uses `apply()` which is looping, it still runs faster compared to logics using Python looping and/or list comprehension.

Benchmarking shows that this solution run at 2.57ms compared to other solutions with 41.7ms, 142ms and 288ms.

Comment: The `apply` section uses a for loop internally though; it's fast though at 2.57ms. how many rows are returned?

Comment: @sammywemmy  Right, I shall revise a bit the wording.  Thanks!

Comment: @sammywemmy  My approach is a bit different, I list the number of overlapping days in each original dataframe row and also get a summary count at the end.  Therefore, the number of rows returned is the number of rows of original dataframe rows as shown in my sample output above.

Comment: fair enough. hopefully the OP puts up a visual of the expected output

Comment: Hmm I ran a test on this for a larger dataset. @sammywemmy :s method ran in 95 seconds while SeaBean :s method ran in 123 seconds

Comment: @sammywemmy  Yup, that would be very helpful.

Comment: @Olba12  Good that you take a benchmarking for larger dataset also.  Then, it depends on what's the layout of result you expect then.   It is up to you to determine which combination of result presentation and execution time that suits you best.  No problem.   :-)

Comment: I've mad an update of how an output could look like @SeaBean

Comment: @Olba12  I think sammywemmy's and others solutions are more readily customized to your required output than mine!  You can choose from one of their answers.  :-)

Comment: Yes, problem is that running 700 000 rows took 95 seconds and I have 40 million  + rows of data haha @SeaBean But thanks!

Comment: @Olba12  Welcome!  Hope next time can help you better!  Good luck and hope you get a very good solution for such huge dataset!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by:

```
print([((df['Start'] <= date) & (date <= df['End'])).sum() for date in d])
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep track of date

```
print([(date, df[(df['Start'] <= date) & (date <= df['End'])]['Category'].nunique()) for date in d])
```

else

```
print([df[(df['Start'] <= date) & (date <= df['End'])]['Category'].nunique() for date in d])
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to be an improvement in speed